# Can I install Nautilus on a Mac using Homebrew? (I see it's included in MacPorts but I'd rather not switch.)

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

As the title says, I would like to install Nautilus on a Mac which is currently using HomeBrew as its package manager.

nautilus doesn't appear in the HomeBrew repository. I could try compiling it from source but I don't know what I'd need to do or install for that to be successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a little bit of program duplication, Homebrew and MacPorts can coexist peacefully. Homebrew lives in `/usr/local`, while MacPorts lives in `/opt/local` (by default), so all you have to do to keep the brewed programs as the defaults on the command line is make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/opt/local/bin` in your shell's `$PATH` variable. Yes, installing MacPorts will use some space, so compiling Nautilus from scratch would be a better option if you're being careful of every bit you write to your HD, but if you have enough extra space you can't go wrong with MacPorts. I actually prefer it over Homebrew for its excellent dependency calculations and its range of included programs, as you've already found. The [documentation](http://guide.macports.org/index.html) is quite good, something I found lacking when I tried Homebrew last year.

So, my advice would be to give MacPorts a try, and if it's too hard/confusing/troublesome you can always try the manual option. For that, you generally download the tarball, unzip it, enter the directory, run `./configure` and look for errors, if none then run `make` and look for errors, if none run `sudo make install` and hopefully you've got yourself a brand-new working copy of Nautilus.

Comment: The [Nautilus portfile](https://github.com/sakuro/macports/blob/master/gnome/nautilus/Portfile) mentions a few patches that are needed as well as a couple of additional steps, so I wouldn't do this manually, but rather go with the MacPorts way.

Comment: This seems like the way to go. I've seen some conflicting info about Homebrew and MacPorts coexisting and it's good to hear that it's possible. I'll give this a try tonight.

Comment: I tried compiling it from scratch earlier and wasn't able to. I'm a little out of my depth there, but it seemed from the errors that it was expecting different (older) versions of things like autoconf than homebrew was installing.